# Count most used words from Django Model

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I got basic Django app with BeautifulSoup webscraped that gets data about Author and Content then saves it to the database. I need to get top 10 most used words from that Content Models. I know how to get the top 10 from a url source but i have to get it from Model, can anyone help me with idea behind that?

```
    views.py
    .............
    for i in posts:
    link = i.find_all('a', {'class': 'blog-button post-read-button post-button-animation'})[0]
    url = link.get('href')  # getting the url of each post
    fixed_url = '######' + url
    content = session.get(fixed_url, verify=False).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    author = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'author-name'})[0].text  # getting the author name
    description = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'post-content'})[0].text  # getting the content of post
    try:
        a = Author.objects.get(name=author)
    except Author.DoesNotExist:
        author_name = author
        author = Author.objects.create(name=author_name)
        author.save()
    Content.objects.get_or_create(description=description, author=a)
    ..............
    models.py
    class Author(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class Content(models.Model):
        description = models.TextField()
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

            def __str__(self):
                return self.description
```

Comment: write some code first and post it if you cannot work it out

Comment: Can you show what the model looks like?

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: 10 Most used words in the description on the Content model?

Comment: yes 10 most used words in the description @hancho

Comment: What I am understanding is that suppose a user get the data first time like this:  `.content_1, author_1` and stored it into DB and second or more time the same or another user can look for the same data i.e. `content_1, author_1` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, from what I understand in the comments, you want the top 10 most used words in the description for a `Content`.

Create a method that splits the content into a list of words and iterate through that list, and use a dictionary to track how many time a word has appeared.

```
class Content(models.Model):
...
...
# Add this method to class
def get_most_used_words(self, count):
    words = {}
    description = self.description.split()
    for word in description:
        if word in words:
            words[word] += 1
        else:
            words[word] = 1
    top_10_words = sorted(words.items(),key=lambda x:-x[1])[:count]
    return top_10_words
```

You can now use the method above like this

```
c = Content.objects.last() # Get the last content
print(c.get_most_used_words(10)) # Get the top 10 most used words
```

Comment: Works great! But how if i want to get top 10 of all Content models into one dict?

Comment: Hi, can you please mark this answer as accepted then since it answers your question.

As for your other question, please try to solve it yourself first and if you can't, then post a question on here with your attempt. 

If you need a hint, you could create an empty dictionary, iterate through your Contents and add each one to the dictionary.